# Having jQuery string comparison issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-selectors

I've got a fiddle going [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/GndB9/) to show what I'm trying to do.

I have a table that is generated dynamically, so the columns could appear in whatever order the user chooses. So, I'm trying to get the index of two specific headers so that I can add a CSS class to those two columns for use later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) here instead (and whenever you need to restrict the element set), since your [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `return` is getting thrown away, like this:

```
//Loop thru the headers and get the Supp elem
var suppCol = $("#my_table th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == "Supp";
});
//Loop thru the headers and get the Report elem
var reportCol = $("#my_table th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == "Report";
});
```

[You can test the updated/working fiddle here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/GndB9/1/).  The alternative using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) would look like tis:

```
var suppCol, reportCol;
$("#my_table th").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), html = $this.html();
    if(html == "Supp") suppCol = $this;
    if(html == "Report") reportCol= $this;
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/GndB9/4/).

Comment: Let me make sure I'm getting this right: the `.each(function() {return})` was basically returning the result to nothing since it was iterating and not actually able to assign my value to anything, right?

Comment: @kchau - Not sure I'm following 100%, but it was returning *every* `<th>`, basically what you had was the same as `var suppCol = $("#my_table th");`, since `.each()` just *returns* the set that it's run on...it's for running someone on every element, but not changing the set, what's exactly what `.filter()` is for :)

Comment: @Nick, I see what I did wrong now. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Nick, PS - your second example for `.each()` alternative is still using `.filter()`. :-P

Comment: @kchau - woops updated, it still works just more expensive and an inappropriate usage :)